# how to enable and disable scripts via the popup menu in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

im trying to make some sort of addons extension for code.org. i want it so that the use can enable dark mode and disable it via the popup menu. i tried hard, but at the end i couldnt find a way to enable and disable scripts using the popup menu.

```
// manifest.json
{
  "name": "code.org addons",
  "description": "code.org addons",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup/index.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
     "matches": [
      "https://*.code.org/*"
     ],
     "js": [
     "jquery/jquery.js",
     "addons/dark.js"
     ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
// popup/index.html
<html>
<h1>addons menu</h1>
<style>
body {
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
}
</style>

<hr>
    <h2>Dark Mode</h2>
    <input id="dark" type="checkbox">
</html>
```

```
//manager.js is blank.
```

Comment: Use a background page and conditionally run `tabs.executeScript()` if dark mode is enabled.

Comment: can you give an example on how to do that? i tried to do what you said but i just cant do it

Comment: hello? are you there?